# applicationConversionService injection error - no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an application conversion service defined in my application-context.xml.

```
<bean id="applicationConversionService"
    class="com.myer.reporting.converter.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean"
    p:messageSource-ref="messageSource"/>
```

I am trying to inject it into one of my other beans.

```
<bean id="bulletinBarMessageRowMapper" 
    class="com.myer.reporting.dao.mapper.BulletinBarMessageRowMapper" 
    scope="prototype"
    p:applicationConversionService-ref="applicationConversionService"/>
```

Where com.myer.reporting.dao.mapper.BulletinBarMessageRowMapper has the following property...

```
public class BulletinBarMessageRowMapper implements RowMapper<BulletinBarMessage>{

    private ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean applicationConversionService;

    public ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean getApplicationConversionService() {
        return applicationConversionService;
    }    
    public void setApplicationConversionService(
            ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean applicationConversionService) {
        this.applicationConversionService = applicationConversionService;
    }
```

Seems pretty straight forward but it is failing with the following error...

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException:
>   Failed to convert property value of type
>   'org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormat
>   tingConversionService' to required type
>   'com.myer.reporting.converter.Applicatio
>   nConversionServiceFactoryBean' for property
>   'applicationConversionService'; nest ed exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [o
>   rg.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService]
>   to require d type
>   [com.myer.reporting.converter.ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean]
>   fo r property 'applicationConversionService': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found

Can someone please tell me why this would fail. I've looked up some doco and there seems to be some mention of a bean named DefaultFormattingConversionService configured automatically for us by Spring which might be interfering however I need more information on what is going wrong here.

The only other thing I can think that might be contributing to this error is that I use...

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService"/>
```

thanks

Comment: The `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean` is a `FactoryBean`. It creates, probably, a `ApplicationConversionService`. Instead of injecting a `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean` change the type to `ApplicationConversionService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So strange thing about this is that instead of injecting via the xml I added an autowire annotation into my class and it just worked!

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean applicationConversionService;
```